# Getting most recent objects in a folder excluding certain strings

Tags: powershell

I have folders that contain files, for the sake of the question, named as follows:

```
a-001.txt 
a-002.txt
b-001.txt
b-002.txt
d-001.txt
d-002.txt
```

Now I am using PowerShell to initially order these files so that the top of the list is the most recent file in the folder:

```
d-002.txt
b-002.txt
a-001.txt 
a-002.txt
b-001.txt
d-001.txt
```

EDIT: I then store the top `X` recent number of files into a variable. However, I want to ignore anything that starts with `A` if I already have one that begins with `A` in my array but still ensure I end up with `X` files which are the most recent. I.e. from above, I would want to end up with below if `X was 4`.

```
d-002.txt
b-002.txt
a-001.txt
b-001.txt
```

This is a simple example, the folders I am dealing with contain 1000s of files - with more complex naming conventions but the logic is the same. How can I handle this in PowerShell?

Comment: Have you tried anything already? Piping Get-ChildItem into Sort into Select would do this easily?

Comment: I forgot an additional part of the logic - see edit.

Comment: My question still stands. I know we can do this but I just need you to show a little effort first. Right now it appears you are asking for code writing service.

Comment: I appreciate that - however, this part of the problem is only a small part of the overall script - and I can't copy paste code as it does not apply the above example. As of now - I have a text file being read into an array, each line being a path. I am running GCI against that path, piped into Where-Object selecting an certain type of file extension for the first filter (this is where I need to insert more logic as above), then piped into Sort-Object for LastAccessTime, finally piped into Select-Object for X.

Comment: That's a little better. Lets work with that then. Sound like the `Where-Object` will be where the changes are made

Comment: My main concern is how it will know that it already has something containing "a" in the array to then skip any further "a" it comes across on the GCI operation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64129/discussion-between-matt-and-pnp).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the logic for any other `Sort-Object` and `Select-Object` criteria as you already have that addressed I present the following.

```
Get-ChildItem $somePath | Select-Object *,@{Label="Prefix";Expression={(($_.Name) -Split "-",2)[0]}} | Group-Object prefix | ForEach-Object{
    $_.Group | Select-Object -First 1 -Property Fullname
}
```

What happens here is that we add a property to the output of `Get-ChildItem` called "Prefix". Now, your criteria might be more complicated but given the sample I assumed the files were being grouped by the contents of the name before the first "-". So we take every file name and build its prefix based on that. The magic comes from `Group-Object` which will group all items and then we just select the first one. In your case that would be the newest X amount. Let me know if you are having trouble integrating this.

Aside from grouping logic any sorting an what not would need to exists before the `Select-Object` in our example above.

**FYI for other readers**

There were issues with OP's actual data since the above code didnt work exactly. We worked it out in chat and using the same logic we able to address the OPs concern. The test data in the question and my answer work as intended.

Comment: From testing, this will return unlimited results skipping duplicates that begin with the same letter. The problem is ensuring we only ever getting X number of results (controlled via a variable) even if it skips duplicates. So, we want 4 results, but if the top 4 files begin with A, it takes the first one, ignores the next 3, then gets 3 more results lower down the ordered list of files.

Comment: @PnP Ok... so i misunderstood and im a little lost. I though you were looking to omit groups of files which is what i was trying to do. So you only want to omit one type of file... the A files. You always want X files from a directory where the A file is unique unless the count is low in which case you take more A files until the A files and non-A files total X?

Comment: I tried my best to explain in the above examples in OP. Perhaps we can take this to chat?